# Xcode 7 - Cell content not displayed into an empty label

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to display a cell content into an empty UILabel, but after I upgraded to Xcode 7, the content didn't show up. I was following the same mechanism and it worked on Xcode 6, but since I'm new to Swift I may have something wrong in the code.

TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct dataModel {
        var name:String
        var val:Double
    }

    let foods = [dataModel(name: "name1", val: 3.3),
        dataModel(name: "name2", val: 5.5)]


    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return foods.count

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let foodCell = foods[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = foodCell.name


        return cell
    }


    var valueToPass:String!
    var valueInt:Int!

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel!.text

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showCalc", sender: self)





    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "showCalc") {

            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! calcViewController
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
        }

    }
}
```

ViewController where I want to display the tapped cell into an empty label:

```
import UIKit

class calcViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var text: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var empty1: UILabel!
    var passedValue:String!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        empty1.text = passedValue
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

As a result, there is no error, but there is nothing displayed inside the empty label.

The other thing I want to achieve is to display the Int value into another label and then do some calculations, but this would be another question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in this code. First you are obviously missing some closing braces. But I assume this is a copy-paste error.

1. Why do you use `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`? Don't you have a segue from the table view cell to the next controller? Then you should get the text label in `prepareForSegue` by using `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.
2. If you like to keep it this way you should use `didSelect...` in stead of `didDeselect...`.
3. You should take the value you want to pass to the next view controller direct from the data and not from the cell. You have the data you present in the table in the foods array.
4. Class names should always start with a capital letter. ALWAYS!
5. Having the data model within the controller is poor design. You should have the struct separated in its own file. In this case you could even hand the complete data object to the next view controller.